# Excel VBA 7.1 comdlg

Tags: excel, vba

This is for VBA 7.1 excel's macro. I am trying to export a file to a location and it crashes at this part.

The error I am running into is "Can't find project or library". The reference not found is the "comDlg". I know this is a referencing error. However, I am unsure how to resolve it.

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
comDlg.Filter = "XML Files"
comDlg.DialogTitle = "Save Export File As..."
comDlg.ShowSave

txtExportFile.Text = comDlg.Filename
```

I had the same issue with a UCase() function call, a simple VBA.UCase() solved it. If you need any more information please let me know. I believe this macro/excel sheet was made on an older version and carried over to a 64bit Windows 10.

Comment: You maybe have a wrong/missing reference. Try, please checking your workbook references and un-tick the wrong one (it will display 'missing')...

Comment: It says MISSING: Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP3)

Comment: `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` would probably be a less problem-prone approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use VB6 controls that are unsupported in a 64-bit VBA host. Try a 32-bit Excel install, but consider using `Application.GetSaveAsFileName`/`GetOpenFileName` for this kind of thing:

```vb
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
    Dim promptResult As Variant
    promptResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("file.xml", "XML Files (*.xml),*.xml", 1, "Save Export File As...")
    If VarType(promptResult) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub 'prompt was cancelled
    txtExportFile.Text = CStr(promptResult)
End Sub
```

As for VBA failing to resolve the `UCase` function, ...wild things happen with broken project references: I'd expect these to just go away once the legacy 32-bit stuff is removed from the project.

Comment: These lines of code mixed with unchecking the Missing reference worked for me. Thanks a ton!